# Stop Redactor automatically creating hyperlinks

Tags: redactor

Each time I write a link such as www.link.com Redactor automatically turns it into an active hyperlink. Is there a way to turn this function off?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [autoparse](https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/autoparse/) option to deactivate that behaviour in the [redactor configs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/changes-in-craft-3.html#rich-text-fields)

Go to: `config/redactor/` and add this I believe (untested):

```
{
  "whatever": true,
  "autoparseStart": false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out though the docs:

autoparseLinks: false